# PHP: Separating Values from Text

Tags: php

I have a list of values that I'm grabbing from a website, these are a few lines that I grabbed.

```
 [{"durationString":"1 hour",
"programStatus":null,
"channelId":309,
"episodeNo":"0",
"title":"Nostradamus Effect",
"altSynopsis":null,
"startTimeMilis":1296543600000,
"id":1006843665,
"endTime":"Tue Feb 01 16:00:00 SGT 2011"
```

I'd like to separate and print only the ones I'm interested in, such as only title and channelID. How should I go about doing it?

Also there are multiple values of titles and endTime, I'd like to display all of them out

Solved it by using the code

```
foreach($values as $val){
   echo $val["displayStartTime"];
   echo " ";
   echo $val["channelNumber"];
   echo " ";
   echo $val["channelName"];
   echo ", ";
   echo $val["title"];
   echo "<br>";
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're dealing with JSON, so use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode):

```
$values = json_decode($text, true);
echo $values[0]['channelId'];
```

Comment: That code works for the those that do not have multiple values - channelID, channelName. But there are many values for Title and endTime. Is there anyway that I can display all of them out?

Comment: @Ying What `json_decode` gives you is a standard PHP array. Try `var_dump($values)` to see its contents. To output all values of an array you need to loop through it. Maybe you should read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) or follow a tutorial, or give us more concrete data for more concrete answers.